# Unable to do forwarding in BIND DNS?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, bind, forwarding

I have BIND working on Windows Server 2003. I want to forward my queries to another server. Recursion is working but forwarding is not working. Can you guide me to set it up? I have given the following in the options:

```
options { 
       directory "c:\named\zones"; 
       allow-transfer { none; }; 
       forward only; 
       forwarders { 8.8.8.8 ; }; 
       recursion no;
};
```

Is the format for forwarding correct in the above.

If not what is the format. Am i to give any port number in the forwarders line? Does forwarding have any particular port number?

Thank You in advance....

Comment: That configuration should work. Do you get any errors in the log files?

Answer (score 1):

Recursion should not be working, as you have "recursion no;".

```
options {
  recursion yes;
  allow-recursion { localhost; };
  forward only;
  forwarders { 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; };
};
```